# Magento image import throws error message

Tags: csv, magento, import

I am trying to import images into Magento in my CSV, but have no luck at all. When I put the images in the wrong folder, the products are imported perfectly (but obviously without the images), but when I put the images in the right folder I get this error message:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (`attribute_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`)

I am not sure what to do here, so any help with this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: How you are adding images?...Create an "import" folder inside "media". Add all your images in that folder. And use only image name in your CSV. That's all you need to do if you are using default magento import feature.

Comment: I added the images in subfolders (in media/import), which didn't work. When I added one image directly in the import folder it worked. When I then tried importing the images in subfolders again, it worked. Not sure why it worked, but I am glad that it does.

Comment: I never said subfolder. You need to add those images inside "import" folder. Not inside any subfolders inside "import". Like if you have an image named "image1.jpeg" inside media/import directory then just add the image name "image1.jpeg" in the product CSV file. It will work.

Comment: Yes I know you didn't say anything about sub folders, but that is what I did at the start. And it should work. When I skipped the subfolders it did work. Went back to putting them in subfolders, and that worked as well. So it does work now, I just don't know why it wasn't working at the start, since I should be able to use sub folders in the import folder.